# Reading data as Parquet for dynamic schemas

Tags: arrays, string, dataframe, apache-spark, parquet

I am receiving my input data in the below formats. As the schema is changing, I am getting issues while reading as parquet using spark. How to handle such scenarios.

```
root
 |-- EMPID: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- EMPNAME: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- CNTRY: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 
root
 |-- EMPID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- EMPNAME: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CNTRY: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: What's the issue you are getting reading it as parquet ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The schema that we are expecting is array(string) so if there are input values of string. It is failing